# ReactJS - passing data between components

Tags: reactjs

I want to passing data between components but I have a problem. Not getting any error as long as I don't passing data yet, it's fine. When I try to show the props in the console, I can easily see what I want **(history,match,location,AuthStore)**. But when I try to pass the data, I can only see **value** and **AuthStore** in the console and value returns empty. Where am I wrong?

front.layout.js

```
import Profile from '../../Views/profile'

const Layout = (props) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    props.AuthStore.getToken();
    const history = useHistory();


useEffect(() => {
    const token =
        props.AuthStore.appState != null
            ? props.AuthStore.appState.user.access_token
            : null;
    axios
        .post(
            "/api/authenticate",
            {},
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
                },
            }
        )
        .then((res) => {
            if (!res.data.isLoggedIn) {
                history.push("/login");
            }
            setUser(res.data.user);
            setIsLoggedIn(res.data.isLoggedIn);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            history.push("/login");
        });
}, []);

return (
<>
    <Profile value={user} />
</>
)
```

index.js

```
const Profile = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    const { params } = props.match;
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    const history = useHistory();
if(props.location.key){
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(
                `/api/${params.username}`,

                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization:
                            "Bearer " +
                            props.AuthStore.appState.user.access_token,
                    },
                }
            )
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.data.username) {
                    setData(res.data);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
            
    }, []);
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you `console.log(res.data.user)`?

Comment: i can see my user datas